# AWS Athena and trusted entity in a role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

When I was going over a role on my AWS account , I saw an IAM role while have the below trusted entity under trust relationship. I saw AWS Lambda also as a trusted entity. In case AWS Lambda , I usually associate a role with the lambda and I guess AWS Lambda needs to be added as trusted entity in order to use that role to access the resources it wants. However in case of Athena , I am not sure where it is associated with a role and why it would need to be added as trusted entity.

The identity provider(s) athena.amazonaws.com

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking. Are you saying that you are trying to create a role to associate with Amazon Athena? I don't think this is possible because Athena is run as a user, while an AWS Lambda function runs independently to a user (eg triggered by an Amazon S3 upload, which is not related to a user).

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein , AWS Lambda has to be added as a trusted entity to use a role and access the resources allowed by the policies in the role. Since Athena cannot use a role , what is the purpose of adding athena as trusted entity for a role?

Comment: I don't think you can (or, at least, it is of no use). When I go to the IAM Console and create a Role, Athena is not offered as a "service that will use this role".

Comment: Thanks for the update , @JohnRotenstein. I saw a role which had athena as trusted entity , but I was curious to understand why it was the case. I now believe , that it may been accidentally added to the policy as it has no use.